# R cannot be resolved to a variable Music Player

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

```
    package com.example.alphamusicplayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Main.java   /AlphaMusicPlayer/src/com/example/alphamusicplayer  line 12 Java Problem

This error is showing up. 
Can you help me solve this one?

Comment: Can you give us the ADT error message you're getting?

Comment: Nvm. I actually fixed it somehow. Can you help me with something else?

Comment: What else do you want help with?

Comment: I edited it. the post now is the problem I need help with. I was building a music player app and I cannot turn the project into apk as I m getting those errors. If you want I can email you the whole folder of the project so you can check it? I really want to finish this asap. Thank you for noticing my problem.